# Python: finally gives SyntaxError

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm making a server with socket in Python. In line 22 is the SyntaxError.

```
import socket

def create_socket():
    global s
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(("", 50000))
        s.listen(1)
    except:
        print("[-] Can't start socket")
def listener():
    global s
    try:
        while True:
            msg, ip = s.accept()
            while True:
                data = msg.recv(1024)  
                if not data:
                    msg.close()
                    break
                print("[{}] {}".format(ip[0], data.decode())
    finally:
        s.close()

create_socket()
listener()
```

Error:

```
line 22
    finally:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I'm doing wrong?
why is there this error?

Comment: `print("[{}] {}".format(ip[0], data.decode())` <- 3 * `(`, 2 * `)`

Comment: Nearly always a missing `)` on the previous line.

Comment: As @AChampion suggested, your print is missing a final `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
print("[{}] {}".format(ip[0], data.decode())
```

Your missing a ")" at the end it should be

```
print("[{}] {}".format(ip[0], data.decode()))
```